# Find $\mathbb{E}\{M W V V^H W^H M^H \}$ in the following case:

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, expected-value

Let $M$ be an $n \times p$ matrix with complex Gaussian elements with mean $= \mu$ and variance $= \sigma^2$. Also, define matrix $W$ as a $p \times m$ matrix for which the columns are of unit norm. Finally, define vector $V=[v_1,\ldots,v_m]^T$ of dimension $m \times 1$, where $\mathbb{E}\{ |v_i|^2 \}=a$, $\forall i$. Assume that $M$, $W$ and $V$ are independent. We denote by $(\cdot)^H$ the conjugate transpose of $(\cdot)$.

Using the above definitions and assumptions, can we calculate
$\mathbb{E}\{M W V V^H W^H M^H  \}$? if so, how to do it?